# Unknown domain pointing to my VPS running a website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

There is an unknown domain pointing to my website. I'd like to filter these domain so they can't point to my website. I'm running rails 5.1.4 with ruby 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should really handle this within your web server (nginx, apache, etc.) but if you must,

```
class ApplicationController < ActiveController::Base
  WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = %w{mydomain.com leosdomain.com}
  before_action do 
    unless WHITELISTED_DOMAINS.include(request.host) 
      return redirect_to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122525/unknown-domain-pointing-to-my-vps-running-a-website"
    end
  end
end
```